# Why can't implicit conversion be used to reduce the number of methods needing definition?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

This is Prof. Oderdki's example class called Rational, simplified for emphasis:

> ```
> class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
>     def + (that: Rational): Rational =
>         new Rational(this.numer * that.denom + that.numer * this.denom, 
>                      this.denom * that.denom)
>     def + (that: Int): Rational = 
>         new Rational(this.numer + that * this.denom, this.denom)
> ```
>
> //       implicit def IntToRational(a: Int) = new Rational(a)  }

It won't work for the expression:

> ```
> 1 + new Rational(1, 2)
> ```

unless I uncomment the implicit function intToRational which allows Scala to automatically convert the l.h.s. to Rational.  *My question is this:  If I have to define a conversion function to handle when the Int is on the l.h.s., why do I have to define a method that takes Ints when they occur on the r.h.s.?*

To put the question another way, why can't the Scala compiler just convert the Int argument to a Rational so my first definition of '+' (which takes a Rational parameter) works for **both** cases?

It seems to me that Scala is such a clever language there might be a way of declaring a class to be "commutative" in its methods, so that the compiler is free to make such substitutions.  Then, the expressions:

> ```
> Rational(1, 2) + 1
> ```

and

> ```
> 1 + Rational(1, 2)
> ```

both get handled the same way, and by the same method.

I'm thinking this is one of those questions which is challenging to answer because depending on who you ask, the answer is either very obvious or very subtle.  I think this is a question worth addressing.  BTW, I LOVE Prof. Oderski's class's on Coursera!

Comment: One big issue is that Scala operators are polymorphic (and natively implemented as single-dispatch methods) - this unfortunately opens up a can of worms. The implicit actually keeps the fundamental operation "explicit" and consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Implicits can be used on both sides, but at the cost of efficiency: adding an `Int` is a simpler operation.

Usually you care about efficiency with basic math like this.

And because of that, you usually would write not `intToRational` for the LHS but

```
implicit class IntRationalOps(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(r: Rational) = r + i
}
```

In cases where efficiency is not so important and it is okay to always perform the conversion (for math or other things), the implicit can help.  (In cases where it is not a good idea to convert everywhere, the `IntRationalOps` approach can still be used.)

Comment: Thanks, Rex!  I appreciate knowing how to address efficiency concerns, but I am also very curious as to how the problem could be solved if I had no concern for efficiency.  What if I simply wanted to have both expressions (i.e., Int + Rational, Rational + Int) handled by the same method?  You hinted that "Implicits can be used on both sides".  So, how would you do it?

Comment: @user3260503 - Just drop the `+(that: Int)` method and the conversion will generate a `Rational` from an `Int` for the other method.

Comment: You know, Rex, that was the very _first_ thing I tried, (in fact the whole reason for the post) and it doesn't work.  The worksheet gives an error message like: type mismatch; found :Int(1) required :chap6.Rational Anybody understand why it doesn't work?!

Comment: @user3260503 - You need the implicit somewhere it can be found.  Put it in a companion object or otherwise outside the class.  (E.g. `object Rational { implicit def intToRational ... }`)